# Aplicar en bootstrap la regla justify-content: space-between; en el menu de navegación

Tags: bootstrap

En el menu de navegacion tengo lo siguiente

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Viajes Chile</a> <button aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Quienes somos</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Destacados</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacto</a>
                        </li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Ahora bien , necesito que el término VIAJES CHILE esté hacia la izquierda y el resto de los botones hacia  la derecha . Así como queda cuando se utiliza la regla css  `justify-content: space-between; }`    
No me da resultado . Quisiera saber como puede hacerse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He probado el código que publicas y veo que con Bootstrap 4.1 funciona según quieres: el botón de VIAJES CHILE a la izquierda y el resto a la derecha. Al menos usando Chrome y Mozilla.

Pero si uso Bootstrap 5 efectivamente no funciona. Para solucionarlo puedes aplicar la clase **ms-auto** aplicada a ul en lugar de ml-auto.
La causa de esta diferencia está en que la versión 5 de Bootstrap cambia lo de left (ml es margin left) por start (ms es margin start).

Si no has modificado las reglas CSS de Bootstrapp, debiera funcionarte. Si no puede usar la regla **justify-content: end** aplicada al contenedor de la lista ul (el div id="navbarSupportedContent"). O poner a mano los márgenes también con CSS: margin-left: auto.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Un placer ayudar.